# the connection between list and the list view from the web part

Tags: web-part, list, list-view

I’m using SharePoint 2007, Custom list.

I have created 2 difference views on my list. 
on the home page I create 2 web-parts, one for each view.

**I need to implement the next thing:**

1. When I modified view(e.g: removed/add column tec..) I want to see the result on the web-part (the web-part placed on the home page).
2. When I change the default view, I need the option to implement these changes on all other non default view.

Comment: Start accepting some answers liron if you want people to carry on helping you, 33% is pretty low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a web part to a page displaying a certain a copy of that view is made **as it was at that point.**

If you later make changes to a view - like adding/removing fields or putting filter/sorting in then that won't effect on the page.

Filtering by web part connections - sure, see - [Microsoft SharePoint - Connect data in Web Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx)

Comment: Ryan is right... you have to perform it manually to each page.